# Excel Date in Java

Tags: java, excel, date

How should I go about representing an Excel date in Java? Example January 15, 1900 is the #15 (Excel Date 15). I can't seem to come up with a code that processes the correct Excel date for the date I input. I know already that the Excel date needs to be 1 less than the date I entered. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Java date to excel date representation](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12475331)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, Mr. Polywhirl. I read that question and it is asking for time vs an actual date.

Comment: Are you using/have you tried Apache POI? http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: No, I have not. I am also not familiar with it. I thought this would be simply using the calendar and subtracting 1 from the date I input but clearly that is not the case here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373619/1575188

Answer (score 0):

```
     Date excelDate = aDate;
     int counter = 1;
     Date d4 = new Date(1, 1, 1900);

     while (!d4.equals(excelDate))
     {
         d4.next();
         counter++;
     }
      return counter ;
```

Use the while loop to compare the date inputted by the user versus `d4` which will then be incremented by `.next()` method. `counter` will go up until `d4` becomes the same date as `excelDate` and will return the correct "number date".

Comment: I figured this part out last night but where I keep missing something is in the test class. Somehow regardless of what I input it comes out wrong. I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: create a new date object in the test class, and use JOptionPane to get the month day and year. Then call the iExcel method `myObj.iExcel(myDate)` would what it would look like, with `myDate` being the object created.

Comment: I ended up figuring out what I was doing wrong a few hours ago. I tend to over analyze things. I missed something simple. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Wait ... if myObj is not not in my test class how could I use that? I know I would have to create a new object but then my other objects are changed. I keep getting an error.