# Java Convert 'Excel Date Serial Number' to 'DateTime'

Tags: java, excel, datetime

How convert 'excel date serial number'(i.e. 33257.415972222225) to DateTime(i.e. 19/01/1991 09:59:00) using Java?

Comment: That's close - but that's only for the date and not for the time @Ivan.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs java `Date` object stores both date and time. And if you are talking about string representation then using appropriate format in `SimpleDateFormat` will resolve that issue to

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - not familiar with Java @Ivan.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at the [Source code of Apache POI](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.java), method `DateUtils#getLocalDateTime(double date, boolean use1904windowing, boolean roundSeconds)`. This utility class offers more handy methods for working with Excel dates.

Comment: This saved me a lot of code (and is working perfect for my use case)

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since *[January 0, 1900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing)*, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day: `ddddd.tttttt`.
This is called *serial date* or *serial date-time*.

The linked documentation from Microsoft seems to be quite clear.

MS [DATEVALUE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) states:

> Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations.
> By default, January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,447 days after January 1, 1900

Well, I'm going to check this statement:

```
LocalDate testDate = LocalDate.of(1900, Month.JANUARY, 1).plusDays(39447);
System.out.println(testDate);// prints 2008-01-02
```

39,447 days after *January 1, 1900* it's indeed... *January 2, 2008*!

**Why is that?**

The fact that dates in Excel are represented by the number of days starting from an *epoch* (December 30, 1899 or January 1, 1900 or 1904...) is only a part of the story.

I found an ultimate answer here: [Dates And Times In Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) (some god or Whoever may bless these guys).

The developers who implemented the date routines in Excel introduced deliberately a bug for compatibility with the same known issue from [Lotus 1-2-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_1-2-3).

***They treated the year 1900 as a leap year but it's not***,
so any date exceeding February 28, 1900 it's a day more than the actual date.

That's why Excel thinks that *January 1, 2008* is represented by the number 39448: because it is 39,448 *units* after *January 0, 1900* (yes, Excel thinks *zero*) - ie *39,447 days* plus *February 29, 1900*.

Excel can also treat the date portion of a serial date as the number of days since January 0, 1904; this mode is called *1904-mode* or *1904-system* and it's used for compatibility with the Macintosh systems.

Since Excel dates don't carry any time-zone information - it's only a number - it's better to use Java classes like [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)/[`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) to represent such values without a time-zone information.

Well, in pratice - for nowadays dates - one may figure Excel epoch starting from *December 30, 1900* but it's not.

**Excel demo** - date format is *dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss*

[image: 7]

<sub>Dates are inserted as the number on the left</sub>

**A class suitable for the required conversion:**

```
public class SerialDate {

    //days from 1899-12-31 to Instant.EPOCH (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)
    public static final long EPOCH = -25568L;
    
    private long serialDays;
    private double serialTime;
    private long epochDays;
    private long daySeconds;
    
    /**
     * @param date number of Excel-days since <i>January 0, 1899</i>
     */
    public SerialDate(long date) {
        serialDays = date;
        if (date > 59)//Lotus123 bug
            --date;
        epochDays = EPOCH + date;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param date number of days since <i>January 0, 1899</i> with a time fraction
     */
    public SerialDate(double date) {
        this((long)date);
        serialTime = date - serialDays;
        daySeconds = Math.round(serialTime * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    
    /**
     * @return days since 1970-01-01
     */
    public long toEpochDays() {
        return epochDays;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return seconds of the day for this SerialDate
     */
    public long toDaySeconds() {
        return daySeconds;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return a value suitable for an Excel date
     */
    public double getSerialDate() {
        return serialTime + serialDays;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
SerialDate sd = new SerialDate(33257.415972222225);
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.ofEpochDay(sd.toEpochDays()),
        LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(sd.toDaySeconds()));
System.out.println(dt);//prints 1991-01-19T09:59
```